# How to Convert POST request from POSTMAN to .exe or .jar?

Tags: javascript, api, postman, executable, executable-jar

I am using defect management tool and that tool can run external executable file if you provide path to it. I have my POST request ready in POSTMAN having bearer token and body with it. I would like to convert this POST request with body and bearer token to .exe or .jar file which I can put on server and give path in my tool to excute it from the tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a POST request and get the response back as text so you can do something with it, then [CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is maybe the tool you are looking for. It is build in into modern versions of Windows, but if you don't have it, you can obtain it from the official [curl page](https://curl.haxx.se/).

A sample request looks like this (a POST with a JSON body):

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"description":"login is not working!","user":"John Doe"}' \
  http://localhost:8443/software/api/v0/6/issues
```

with commandline commands you can pipe it to a file (by attaching `> c:\temp\issues.txt`) or any other desired endpoint.

If you need a bearer token, then you can find an good explanation [here](https://medium.com/@nieldw/using-curl-to-authenticate-with-jwt-bearer-tokens-55b7fac506bd) on how to do that.

Always try to use known tools over homebrew software, because it works, it is documented and you can get easy help from other users of that tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Before that the `.EXE` or `.jar` file should listen to a `PORT` to receive the `Request`.
So you should properly implement a `HTTP-Listener` in your `.EXE` or `.jar` program. Then specify the port in `Postman`.

**For example**
If the program listen to the port `8000` in `localhost`. You should add `http://localhost:8000/` in `Postman`

Comment: I got that. In Postman my request look like POST https://localhost:8443/software/api/v0/6/issues. I am successfully able to POST an issue in my software using POSTMAN. What to do after that to convert it to .exe or .jar with Bearer Token and BODY data ?? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Can your describe what you want to really archive?

Comment: I want to convert my POST request from POSTMAN to .exe or .jar .

Comment: The is nothing to convert. The request has common format. You can receive the request from `.EXE` without any conversion. Are you using Java?